# AndroidPlot graphing library: How to add initial offset to bar graph

Tags: android, androidplot

I using the AndroidPlot graphing library to make a bar graph, like so:

[image: AndroidPlot graph]

However, the months Jan and Dec are getting cut off.  Does AndroidPlot have any kind of mechanism to offset this so that there's whitespace before Jan and after Dec?

I'm already using these methods to set various other margins and paddings in the graph:

```
mySimpleXYPlot.setBorderStyle(Plot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);
mySimpleXYPlot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
mySimpleXYPlot.setPlotPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
mySimpleXYPlot.setGridPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setPadding(40, 20, 30, 30);
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setSize(new SizeMetrics(0, SizeLayoutType.FILL, 0, SizeLayoutType.FILL));
```

but changing the values in these methods has no effect on offsetting Jan or Dec.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem, but found that`MyXYPLot.setGridPadding(100, 0, 100, 0);` helped.

Comment: I have just solved the same problem, thank you so much!